# Coding Pattern for Namespaced & inherited Form Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-5.2

### Current Form Objects

#### app/form_models/registration/step1.rb

```
module Registration
  class Step1
    include ActiveModel::Model
    #Common code
    #Unique code

    private
    #Common code
    #Unique code
  end
end
```

#### app/form_models/registration/step2.rb

```
module Registration
  class Step2
    include ActiveModel::Model
    #Common code
    #Unique code

    private
    #Common code
    #Unique code
  end
end
```

What is the preferred way to refactor this to avoid `#Common Code` from being repeated?
Should I create another class and inherit from it? If so is this the correct pattern?

## Possible new Form Objects Pattern

#### app/form_models/registration/base.rb

```
module Registration
  class Base
    include ActiveModel::Model
    #Common code

    private
    #Common code
  end
end
```

#### app/form_models/registration/step1.rb

Is this the correct way to inherit a named spaced form object?

```
module Registration
  class Step1<Registration::Base
    #Unique code
    private
    #Unique code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proper way is:

```
module Registration
  class Step1 < Base
    #Unique code
    private
    #Unique code
  end
end
```